# On collapse for mobile show all boostrap sub menus as open

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Im currently using wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php to create bootstrap navigation menus on Wordpress. I have a website to build where the customer needs the parent of a navigation sub menu to be clickable. I have found the code to modify wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php so that it allows the parent to become a link. This however leads to issues on smaller devices.

```
        // If item has_children add atts to a.
        if ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
            $atts['href']           = '#';
            $atts['data-toggle']    = 'dropdown';
            $atts['class']          = 'dropdown-toggle';
            $atts['aria-haspopup']  = 'true';
        } else {
            $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : 
        '';
        }

  $(window).resize(function() {
  //1200 is my modified breakpoint on this design for the collapse menu 
    if ($(window).width() < 1200)  {
      $(".dropdown-toggle").attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
    } else {
      $(".dropdown-toggle").removeAttr('data-toggle dropdown');
    }
  });
```

As the parent menu item is usually an clickable event that opens up the sub menu to show the children links, and this functionality has now been changed, it no longer works on anything but a desktop browser that can show hover events.

I have spent a fair bit of time trying to work out how to get around this, and the only way I can think of doing it is that on smaller devices showing the collapse bootstrap menu, that somewhere how the menu by default is expanded to show all parent and children items.

I have been unable to find a way to get this to work however. Does anyone know how this might be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. Using your own code On mobile devices you can simply add `preventDefault()`. This will prevent the default action of the event will from being triggered; in other words the anchor link will not navigate to the `href` pointer, but instead, in your case it will trigger the dropdown menu.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1200)  {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
  } else {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();  
    }
  }
});
```

Try it and get back with results.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this originally but it didnt work. Just to be sure I tried your code and still on mobile I get the issues. BTW you have a missing closing brace in this code.. Should be:    $(".dropdown-toggle").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();  
    });